# Extract words between doubles quotes in a variable in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr, stringi

I want to extract the name from the following input which is of the form as shown in brackets

```
# Example of the input in brackets('name":"Tale")
name<- c('name":"Tale"','name":"List"')
```

I want to extract the names between the quotes as shown below. Any suggestions?

```
name
Tale
List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the vector to a single column `data.frame`, and then just use `gsub` to remove the `name":` and `"` from the string.

Example:

```
transform(data.frame(name), name = gsub("name\":|\"", "", name))
##   name
## 1 Tale
## 2 List
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `stri_extract_last_words`

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
setDT(list(name=stri_extract_last_words(name)))[]
#   name
#1: Tale
#2: List
```

Comment: I have been going through stringi manual again since yesterday. You are too fast, as usual. :)

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks for the comment and vote.  There are handy functions in that package.

Comment: Yeah, I have been using some of them to handle string extraction for a data set. Fast speed.